# Protractor waitForAngular or .count() not working

Tags: angular, protractor

I have this annoying issue where `count()` is not being updated after a change. My test sets some input values, and then runs the following:

```
$$('.label-entry').count().then(beforeCount => {
    btnSaveLabel.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    $$('.label-entry').count().then(count => expect(count).toEqual(beforeCount + 1));
});
```

The test is supposed to click a save button that makes an API call, wait for that call to end, and check if the # of divs has increased by one (it does when testing manually). Somehow, the test manages to fail. The first call to `count()` works properly, but the second call does not. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="label-entry" *ngFor="let labelEntry of labelEntries">
```

Comment: Based on your example I'd say you might miss some curly brackets `{}` that make a function in the second `then()`. Also I suggent not to use the word 'count' as variable... it's confusing.
 `.then(cnt => { expect(cnt).toEqual(beforeCount+1) });`

Comment: Provide some fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe you don't need your second `then()`, because the `expect` should already resolve your promise.

Can you try this:

```
$$('.label-entry').count().then(beforeCount => {
    btnSaveLabel.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect($$('.label-entry').count()).toEqual(beforeCount + 1);
});
```

or eventually this:

```
$$('.label-entry').count().then(beforeCount => {
    btnSaveLabel.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    //wrap it in a browser.wait() to see, if you get the result before timeout
    browser.wait(expect($$('.label-entry').count()).toEqual(beforeCount + 1), 5000);
});
```

or eventually this (though experimental):

```
$$('.label-entry').count().then(beforeCount => {
    btnSaveLabel.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.wait(($$('.label-entry').count() > beforeCount), 5000);
    expect($$('.label-entry').count()).toEqual(beforeCount + 1);
});
```